# Accessing not public variables

Tags: solidity, web3js, access, visibility

Is it possible as the creater of the smart contract to access a not public variable? E.g.:

```
contract MyContract {

    uint256 someLevel;

    function changeLevel(uint _newLevel) public {
        someLevel = _newLevel;
    }
}
```

How would I access in this case `someLevel` via web3 or at all?

Answer (score 7):

All variables on Ethereum are accessible and readable by everyone in the contract storage, even if they are marked `private`. In the situation where you want to access the contract storage, you can do so using `web3.eth.getStorageAt()`:

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, 0)
.then(console.log);
```

If your contract only stores this one variable, it should be the first index in the storage as noted above.

That being said, in your sample, the variable is not marked private, so then it is made public by default, and there should be a [getter function](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#getter-functions) automatically generated for it. So you can simply call that function to read the variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is very much possible to see values of even private variables stored in the smart contract.

Refer the following blog for more details -

https://hackernoon.com/your-private-solidity-variable-is-not-private-save-it-before-it-becomes-public-52a723f29f5e

Comment: True, though as mentioned in the other answer, this specific variable is not `private`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right in the fact that is possible to access the storage of any contract deployed in ethereum, including private variables.

However, I do not think this answer the question. The questions if this is possible form another contract. Reading the storage of a contract from another contract is not possible (as far as I know). From the point of view of a contract, it can only do what the code in it allows to.

Hope this helps